# Question followup todo list

Tags: feature-request

I would like to have like a todo list of questions that I have asked that I need to make sure they have accepted answers that are correct. This would be just a list of unanswered questions, but it would be nice to have a way to dismiss items (until there is new activity).

Accepting an answer would automatically dismiss an item. If dismissing was too involved.. then just a list of questions with answers that are not accepted would be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for:

> [user:me hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0)

To limit the search to only those questions with at least one answer:

> [user:me hasaccepted:0 answers:1](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1)

I've linked both searches to Stack Overflow, but they work on any Stack Exchange site. Find more search options at [/search](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: For those who find this answer.. Please note that changes you make will take a few minutes to make it into the search results.